# Using multiple (similar) generator expressions

Tags: python, csv, replace, generator, generator-expression

In a csv file, I'm trying to replace certain characters with other characters.

My current code is similar to this:

```
import csv

set1 = set('abc')
set2 = set('def')
set3 = set('ghi')

with open(path, 'r') as input, open(path2, 'w') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input)
    writer = csv.writer(output)

    for row in reader:
            newrow = row
            newrow = [''.join('x' if c in set1 else c for c in item) for item in newrow]
            newrow = [''.join('y' if c in set2 else c for c in item) for item in newrow]
            newrow = [''.join('z' if c in set3 else c for c in item) for item in newrow]

            writer.writerow(newrow)
```

In this example I am only using three generator expressions, but it could easily be more than that.

Does anyone know the right way to do this? My concern is that this structure might not be the fastest (and certainly doesn't look optimal).

Comment: @MartijnPieters: oops! I missed that. Sleepy eyes, I'm afraid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) might be appropriate; something along the lines of

```
replacements = [
    ('abc', 'x'),
    ('def', 'y'),
    ('ghi', 'z'),
]

trans = str.maketrans({ k: v for l, v in replacements for k in l })
```

and

```
new_row = [item.translate(trans) for item in row]
```

Comment: Tried it again tonight and it works! This is the fastest to execute.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop and parameterise the varying parts:

```
newrow = row
for v, s in (('x', set1), ('y', set2), ('z', set3)):
    newrow = [''.join(v if c in s else c for c in item) for item in newrow]
```

If you are replacing characters, don't use sets but a mapping:

```
mapping = dict.fromkeys(set1, 'x')
mapping.update(dict.fromkeys(set2, 'y'))
mapping.update(dict.fromkeys(set3, 'z'))
for row in reader:
    newrow = [''.join(mapping.get(c, c) for c in item) for item in newrow]
```

Comment: Second part of the answer is what I was looking for (way faster to execute).

Answer (score 1):

Here is something that combines both answers in some way and works great (multiple times faster than the code in the question):

```
replacements = [
('abc', 'x'),
('def', 'y'),
('ghi', 'z'),
]

mapping = {a: b for c, b in replacements for a in c}

for row in reader:
    newrow = [''.join(mapping.get(c, c) for c in item) for item in row]
    writer.writerow(newrow)
```

Comment: You don’t have to use `dict()` on the dict. Anyways, sorry to ask, but is there a reason not to use a string translation table? It’s the same as Martijn Pieters’s answer, but specialized to strings.

Comment: I have adjusted my answer accordingly and tried your solution again (see comment).